# Вопрос преобразования числа в разных системах счисления и его сохранения в C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, codeblocks

В C++ есть возможность представлять числа в двоичной, десятичной, восьмеричной и шестнадцатеричной системе счисления.
Пример:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //СС - система счисления
    const int a = 0b101; //101 -> 5. Двоичная СС
    const int b = 10; //100 -> 100. Десятичная СС
    const int c = 0234; // 234 -> 156. Восьмеричная СС
    const int d = 0xFFAA; //FFAA -> 65450. Шестнадцатеричная СС
    return 0;
}
```

Но, есть ли возможность представлять числе в виде СС, которую я хочу. Если я сделаю такой код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    cout << a;
    return 0;
}
```

И введу `0b101`, то очевидно выдаст `0`.
Если попробую так:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    cout << a + b;
    return 0;
}
```

И введу `1001 1001` очевидно выдаст `2002`. Есть ли возможность как-то превратить данное число в двоичную систему, не через функции и строки(как некоторые делают), а именно сохранить в виде `0b1001`? Допустим, введу `1001` и, сделав некоторые действия, он будет считаться `0b1001`.

Comment: *В C++ есть возможность сохранять числа в двоичной, десятичной, восьмеричной и шестнадцатеричной системе счисления.* Заблуждение. Все числа хранятся в памяти в том, что можно назвать бинарным представлением. И хранится ли в переменной типа `int` значение 0234, 0x9С или 156 — неважно, в памяти это все одно и то же. Вопрос в преобразовании при вводе и при выводе...

Comment: @Harry спасибо за исправление, сейчас поправлю.

Comment: Для переключения системы счисления при вводе/выводе, см.:  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setbase  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/showbase

Comment: Если вопрос именно в том, чтобы 1001 интерпретировать, как число в двоичной системе, то - можете попробовать `std::bitset`. В случае, если вам не нужно оперировать битами числа в дальнейшем, то вам в любом случае придётся делать функцию обработки ввода, который интерпретирует "1001" не как 1001, а как 0b1001. В стандартной библиотеке по умолчанию есть флаги форматного ввода-вывода, но там нет двоичной системы счисления. Зато есть десятичная, восьмеричная и шестнадцатиричная: [здесь](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/fmtflags)